# Vue JS One Checkbox unchecking another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to get one checkbox to uncheck another (kinda like radio buttons). I am a little bit of a Vue noob so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here are the two inputs.

```
<label for="'product-'+product.id"
     class="none addon_label"
     :class="{'addon_selected': !selected}"
     >

<input class=""
       type="checkbox" 
       :id="'product-'+product.id"
       :value="false"
       v-model="selected"/>

<div class="v-center">None</div>
</label>

<label :for="'product-'+product.id"
     class="is_flex addon_label"
     :class="{'addon_selected': selected}"
     :data-product-id="product.id">
<div class="checkbox-container">
<input class=""
       type="checkbox"
       :value="true"
       :id="'product-'+product.id"
       v-model="selected"/>
</div>
```

[Recording of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5saU.gif)

Comment: Both `label`s and `input`s have the same `for`/`id` (product-'+product.id), and will thus behave like this. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use radio buttons instead of checkbox:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      product: {id: 1},
      selected: false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.addon_selected {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <label for="'product-'+product.id"
       class="none addon_label"
       :class="{'addon_selected': !selected}"
       >
  <input class=""
         type="radio" 
         :id="'product-'+product.id"
         :value="false"
         v-model="selected"/>
  </label>
  <label :for="'product-'+product.id"
       class="is_flex addon_label"
       :class="{'addon_selected': selected}"
       :data-product-id="product.id">
  <input class=""
         type="radio"
         :value="true"
         :id="'product-'+product.id"
         v-model="selected"/>
         
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need to use checkboxes instead of radio inputs, you can reverse the `true-value` and `false-value` props of one input. This way it will mimic the behavior of the radio buttons.

```js
new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
  selected: false
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<label for="first_input"
     >False</label>
<input
       type="checkbox" 
       id="first_input"
       v-model="selected"
       :true-value="false"
       :false-value="null"/>

<label for="second_input"
     >True</label>
<input
       type="checkbox" 
       id="second_input"
       v-model="selected"
       :false-value="null"/>
       
<br/>
       
Input value: {{ selected }}

</div>
```

Comment: This is really new for me (true-value attribute), but, how to deselect the checkbox? in your solution there is no way to reset the inputs.

Comment: @AndresForonda I've updated the code. setting the `false-value` of both inputs to null will allow to deselect the inputs, while keeping model-bindings for the true-value. concerning the input attributes these are Vue specific attributes, and you may want to familiarize with all of them [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox-1)

Comment: Great, again this is very clever

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that using two variables will be a good approach to have this behavior (checkbox like radio buttons).

There are two methods setInitial and setEnd, each one clear the another input, but the checkbox behavior still the same, so you can clear or reset the inputs by clicking the same input twice.

```js
new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
  initial: false,
  end: false
},

methods: {
  setInitial: function(){
    this.end = false
  },
  setEnd: function(){
    this.initial = false
  }
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label
    class="none addon_label"
    :class="{'addon_selected': !initial}"
  >Initial</label>
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    v-model="initial"
    @click="setInitial"
  />
  ==#==

  <label
    class="is_flex addon_label"
    :class="{'addon_selected': end}"
  >End</label>
  <input
     type="checkbox"
     v-model="end"
     @click="setEnd"
  />
<hr>
Initial {{ initial }} - End {{ end }}
<hr>
  
</div>
```

Please run the snippet and test this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<label for="'product-'+product.id"
     class="none addon_label"
     :class="{'addon_selected': !selected}"
     >

<input class=""
       type="radio" 
       :id="'product-'+product.id"
       :value="checkStatus"
       @change="check($event.target.value)"/>

<div class="v-center">None</div>
</label>

<label :for="'product-'+product.id"
     class="is_flex addon_label"
     :class="{'addon_selected': selected}"
     :data-product-id="product.id">
<div class="checkbox-container">
<input class=""
       type="radio"
       :value="checkStatus"
       :id="'product-'+product.id"
       @change="check($event.target.value)/>
</div>
```

In your script of component, you can define method check() inside of methods.

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            checkStatus: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        check: function(val) {
              this.checkStatus = !val;
        }
    },
}
</script>
```